# How to connect virtual media using python-dracclient

Tags: python

Would just like to ask on how can I connect a remote virtual media (ISO image) to a Dell Power730 server using [python-dracclient](https://github.com/openstack/python-dracclient). I've checked the documentation for python-dracclient from openstack and its code, but I couldn't find any reference for the mounting/connecting virtual media. Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Why do you  think this should be possible?

Comment: Hi @jeroen. Thanks for the reply. Well since dracclient can get all bios, boot device, idrac settings through wsman, I was thinking maybe I’m just missing something here. Hope somebody can shed some light.